# Editing a useParams ID to use as a proper title in React

Tags: reactjs

Here's my Routing

```
<Route path="/marvel" element={<Marvel />} />
<Route path="/marvel/:id" element={<MarvelDetail />} />
```

Here's my Marvel page

```
<a href="/marvel/captain-america-civil-war">
  Captain America: Civil War   
</a>
```

Here's my `Detail` page

```
const { id } = useParams();

<div className="marvel__main-topbar">
  <span className="marvel__main-title">{id}</span>
</div>
```

I have a main page that redirects to any number of topics relating to a specific Marvel movie. If you take a look at the `Detail` page code you'll notice I have a `span` with `{ id }` for the title which displays at the very top of each page. The routing works fine and I'm redirected to the right page, however instead of having the title be `Captain America: Civil War` it makes it `captain-america-civil-war`. I know it does this because it's just copying the route. But how can I make each page have their own proper title instead of one that uses dashes?

**What I've Tried**

I changed the `id` to include the `replace` method but that didn't fully work because it doesn't know when to include a colon or any other special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a separate file that contains an array of marvel objects with the id AND the proper title like so :

marvelDetails.js

```js
const marvelDetails = [
  {
    id: 'captain-america-civil-war',
    title: 'Captain America: Civil War'
  },
];
```

In your Details page:

```js
const {id} = useParams();

// Don't forget to import the marvelDetails.js file
const title = marvelDetails.find((detail) => detail.id === id).title

<div className="marvel__main-topbar">
  <span className="marvel__main-title">{title}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: great idea thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it's giving me a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')` I'm messing around trying to fix but any suggestions?

Comment: @Dagger, make sure that given `id` exists in one of the objects in  `marvelDetails` list and has `title` property as well

Comment: @M.-EH Thanks for your help. I was using `useParams` and not `useParams()` so it wasn't matching the `id` properly.